# filter requests on nginx server when it serves as both http server and reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server serving both as an http server (frontend) on / and reverse proxy on /api, where it forwards the requests to a node server (backend) on the same machine (localhost).

I am using authentication only on the frontend. The backend accepts all incoming requests and does not authenticate again the requests.

I would like to allow all requests coming from the frontend to the backend. I would like to block all requests coming to the backend from other sources (via the reverse proxy of course).

For example, the frontend will try to login the user using the user third-party auth id via https://domain/api/login/id. The reverse proxy will forward it to the backend. This is fine.

I can also access the backend directly from any other machine via https://domain/api/login/id.

My question is the following. I would like to block all requests not originating by the frontend. I have tried figuring out how to find the information but it seems that the X-Real-IP header always refers to the browser originating the request (either by using the frontend or directly). I am wondering if there is any header I can set in the reverse proxy which will tell the backend that this is an allowed call, or even use nginx own allow/deny rules. Right now, I do not manage to make a distinction between the two types of requests.

Thank you very much!

Comment: One possibility is to set a header on the frontend initiated requests, but this is visible to the user, who can then add these headers to requests originating from other sources.

Comment: This is usually solved using some kind of an auth cookie that is being set by your frontend and then being checked by your API backend. Everything else I can imagine can be easily spoofed.

Comment: Thank you. I have the thirdparty (auth0) cookie and send it to the backend. I am not sure how to authenticate it there though. I guess I should not send an authentication request every time I get an API call. The backend also is behind the reverse proxy.